# Conectar front-end ao banco de dados, com electron e NextJS e sequelize

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, electron, next.js

Em minha aplicação tenho uma janela onde irei carregar uma tabela baseada nos produtos que estão cadastrados no banco de dados.Esta janela é um componente React. Eu esperava utilizar o modulo `ipcRenderer` do electron, para mandar uma uma requisição para a main do programa assim que a janela carregasse. E então a main faria a chamada ao banco de dados e retornaria os dados necessarios. Porém ao tentar fazer isso no lado da renderer ocorre o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que notei foi que este erro ocorre em todas as partes do meu component exeto quando ele é executado por um evento como `onClick()`. E também que se eu jogar no console `console.log(ipcRenderer)` ele acaba entendendo que isso é um evento e que dentro tem as funções "on" e "send", mas ao usar o `ipcRenderer.send()` ou `ipcRenderer.on()` este erro acontece.
Alguem sabe alguma alternativa para realizar a comunicação, ou uma solução para este problema.
Segue o código do meu main e do meu componente:

Main:

```
import { app, ipcMain, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import serve from 'electron-serve';
import { createWindow } from './helpers';
import startDataBase from '../backend/dataBase';
import { addItem } from '../backend/dataBase/crud';
import path from 'path'

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

if (isProd) {
    serve({ directory: 'app' });
} else {
    app.setPath('userData', `${app.getPath('userData')} (development)`);
}

(async() => {
    await app.whenReady();
    startDataBase()

    const mainWindow = createWindow('main', {
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        center: true,
    });

    loadUrl(mainWindow, 'home')

    function menuNewCotation() {
        let menuNewCotation
        ipcMain.on('openMenuNewCotation', async() => {
            if (!menuNewCotation) {
                menuNewCotation = await createWindow('newCotation', {
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600,
                    parent: mainWindow

                })
            }
            menuNewCotation.on('close', () => menuNewCotation = null)
            loadUrl(menuNewCotation, 'newCotation')

            menuProductsRegister()
            listenRegisterProduct()
            newCotationListeners()
        })

        function listenRegisterProduct() {
            ipcMain.on('sendDataToBackend', async(event, arg) => {
                event.reply('sendResponseToFrontend', await addItem(arg, 'product'))
            })
        }

        function menuProductsRegister() {
            let menuProductsRegister
            ipcMain.on('openMenuProductsRegister', async() => {
                if (!menuProductsRegister) {

                    menuProductsRegister = await createWindow('menuProductsRegister', {
                        width: 800,
                        height: 600,
                        parent: mainWindow,
                    })
                    loadUrl(menuProductsRegister, 'registerProducts')
                }
                menuProductsRegister.on('close', () => menuProductsRegister = null)
            })
        }

        function newCotationListeners() {
            ipcMain.on('requestDataTeste', (event) => {
                event.reply('requestDataToBackend', { teste: 'teste' })
            })

        }
    }

    menuNewCotation()

    app.on('ready', mainWindow.maximize())

})();

//Start the HTML
async function loadUrl(window, rote) {
    if (isProd) {
        await window.loadURL(`app://./${rote}.htm`);
    } else {
        const port = process.argv[2];
        await window.loadURL(`http://localhost:${port}/${rote}`);
    }
}

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

Componente:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
import Button from '../components/button/button'
import style from '../styles/newCotation.module.css'

function NewCotation() {
    
    function renderProducts() {
    ipcRenderer.send('requestDataTeste')
    ipcRenderer.on('requestDataToBackend',(event,arg) => {
        console.log(arg)
    })
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
    function renderProviders() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className={`flex flex-col 
        rounded-xl bg-white
        items-center
         ${style.newCotation} font-extrabold`}    
         >
            <div className={`w-full rounded-xl overflow-hidden bg-gray-400 flex flex-row`}>
                <div className='w-3/4 text-center'>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Produtos</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div onLoad={() => {
                        ipcRenderer.send('requestDataTeste')
                        ipcRenderer.on('requestDataToBackend', (event, arg) => {
                            console.log(arg)
                        })
                    }}>
                        {renderProducts()}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='w-1/4 text-center'>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Fornecedores</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {renderProviders()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between w-full'>
                <Button className='bg-yellow-600 
                rounded-md h-8 w-48 
                text-white font-bold
                m-5'
                    onClick={() => {
                        ipcRenderer.send('openMenuProductsRegister')
                    }}>
                    Cadastrar Produtos
                </Button>
                <Button className='bg-yellow-600 
                rounded-md h-8 w-48 
                text-white font-bold
                m-5'
                    onClick={() => {
                        ipcRenderer.send('openMenuProviderRegister')
                    }}>
                    Cadastrar Fornecedores
                </Button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default NewCotation
```

Comment: O ipcRenderer não está disponível automaticamente no renderer process por motivo de segurança, é preciso utilizar uma estratégia de [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts).

Comment: Eu pensei em utilizar um preload para fazer a requisição mas não sei como devolver o resultado para a renderer. A única forma que conheço é o ipcRenderer, mas nesse caso não está funcionando.

Comment: No seu preloader.js (ver link do comentário anterior) você faz o require do ipcRenderer e coloca dentro do objeto window do processo de renderização. O link que te passei mostra um exemplo disso (mas sem usar o ipcRenderer).

Comment: Acabei de tentar está alternativa, acabou me retornando dois erros:
1º: window is not defined(depois tendei usar global no lugar de window, mas retornou undefined)
2º Unable to load preload script: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled

Answer (score -2):

juliomalves resolveu meu problema. Só tive que colocar o ipcRenderer para rodar dentro de um `useEffect()` do React. desta forma `useEffect(() => {ipcRenderer.send("...")})`